# ExceptionInInitializerError while inserting Excel data in a database in Java Swing

Tags: java, mysql, excel, swing

I am getting this error while executing my java swing code. 
How to solve this? I have found some questions similar to this but didn't got the required answers.

I am making a desktop application which will read tables from excel sheet and will update the table values in a database.

Here is the code snippet:
Main code from where I am reading and calling the database query

```
if (flag) {

    int j=0;
    String[] productArray= new String[2];


    for (int i = 0; i < cr.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) { 


        String colKeyOrTabName = getCellValueAsString((cr
                .getCell(firstCell + i)));
        colKeyOrTabName=colKeyOrTabName.replaceAll(" ", "");
        //colKeyOrTabName=colKeyOrTabName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", "");
        productArray[j]=colKeyOrTabName;
        j++;
        //System.out.println(" "+ colKeyOrTabName);


    }

    if(!productArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("code")){
    DBConfig.insertCodes(productArray[0], productArray[1]); 
    }
    /*Ends Here*/
    rowNo++;
    continue;
}
```

DB Code :

```
 public class DBConfig {


private static BasicDataSource bds = null;

static{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    //  logger.error("Error - " + String.valueOf(e), e);

        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error setting connection with SyntBots database");
    }

    bds = new BasicDataSource();

    // set driver class name
    bds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    // Define Server URL
    bds.setUrl(Config.get("config.db.url"));


    // Define Username
     bds.setUsername(Config.get("config.db.user"));


    // Define Your Password
    bds.setPassword(Config.get("config.db.password"));

}



public static void insertCodes(String code, String value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        // Connection conn = null;
        con = bds.getConnection();

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql = "insert into table(code,value) value('" + code+ "','"+ value+"')";
        try{
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            if(e.getErrorCode() == MYSQL_DUPLICATE_PK ){
                System.out.println("Duplicate Entry");             }
        }

        // con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logger.error("Ignore Error - " + String.valueOf(e), e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }

        if (null != con) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}



}
```

And here is the error(Console output) :

```
    Button clicked
    D:\DesktopApplicationInputSheet
    Sample.xlsx
    D:\DesktopApplicationInputSheet/Sample.xlsx
    Reading sheet: 0, Name: Sheet1
    i: 1
    0
    Display Name :-Polaris Code rowNO - 1
    Display Name :-AOO1 rowNO - 2
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at 
    com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readRequestTable(MainDataEntry.java:249)
        at 

  com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readExcelandWriteonDB(MainDataEntry.java:149)
        at 
    com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readExcelPath(MainDataEntry.java:79)
        at 
    com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry$1.actionPerformed(MainDataEntry.java:57)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at 

  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at 

  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at 
 java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error setting connection with SyntBots database
        at com.dataentry.excel.DBConfig.<clinit>(DBConfig.java:26)
        ... 40 more
```

**Update :**
The Issue is fixed. It was of the case of missing JAR for MySQL driver.
But after that I am facing a new issue. 
Have a look at the console output:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.setTestOnCreate(Z)V
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionPool(BasicDataSource.java:2074)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1920)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
    at com.dataentry.excel.DBConfig.insertCodes(DBConfig.java:59)
    at com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readRequestTable(MainDataEntry.java:249)
    at com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readExcelandWriteonDB(MainDataEntry.java:149)
    at com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry.readExcelPath(MainDataEntry.java:79)
    at com.dataentry.excel.MainDataEntry$1.actionPerformed(MainDataEntry.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found the answer to my problem.
In my case it was related to the version of **commons-pool2-2** jar file.
Instead of **2.4.2**, I was using **2.0**.
After changing the JAR to **2.4.2** it started working as expected.

Also I have used the **mysql-connector-java-5.1.18** to resolve my previous issue.

**NOTE :** What I have found from the internet is that JAR compatibility is also need to fix the program.